# duplicado en arrayadapter android

Tags: android

estoy haciendo mi propio adaptador para meter en un listview, visualmente muestra todo bien. cada linea del list view, se compone de una imagen, un texto y 2 spinners....

Cuando se muestra,aparentemente lo ha hecho genial, y a cada elemetno le ha asignado una foto distinta....

donde esta el problema? pues que cuando me pongo a rellenar el texto del elemento 1, me rellena automaticamente el del 6, si relleno el 2, el 7 tb se autocompleta....no entiendo que sucede,podrian ayudarme??

```
    package com.example.oftecnica2.pruebaaudiobus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by OFTECNICA2 on 12/04/2016.
 */
public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter{


    public Adaptador(Context context, String[] objects) {
        super(context,0,objects);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View listItemView=convertView;
        if (null==convertView){

           listItemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutcartel,parent,false);


        }
       ImageView img=(ImageView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.img);




switch (position) {


    case 0:


        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.uno);
        break;
    case 1:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dos);
        break;
    case 2:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.tres);
        break;
    case 3:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cuatro);
        break;
    case 4:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cinco);
        break;
    case 5:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.seis);
        break;
    case 6:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.siete);
        break;
    case 7:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ocho);
        break;




}





    return listItemView;
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/img" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="509dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txt" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.55">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MODE"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:entries="@array/mode"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.36">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SPEED"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="118dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:entries="@array/speed"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde rellenas el texto? En tu código solo viene donde asignas las imágenes.

Comment: perdona,me he explicado mal, el layout que relleno consta de una imagen, un Edittext y dos spinners...

Comment: el problema viene cuando al ejecutar la app, relleno el edittext del numero 1 y me modifica el 6.... como si hicieran referencia al mismo elemento

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda agregar layoutcartel.xml

Comment: añadido!!!! menudo misterio :S

Answer (score 1):

De cierta forma estas usando la misma vista, si viene dentro de la variable convertView, no se esta creando una nueva vista listItemView:

```
   View listItemView=convertView;
        if (null==convertView){        listItemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutcartel,parent,false);
        }
```

solo infla la vista siempre, cuando se ejecute el método getView():

```
View listItemView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutcartel,parent,false);
```

Comment: Elenasys! eso me ha ayudado mucho...pero ahora tengo otro problema...cuando relleno el primer edittext, hago scroll hacia abajo hasta el ultimo elemento, y vuelvo al primer elemento, se ha reiniciado y puesto el edittext vacio....

como puedo hacer para que se quede quieto y no reinicie los valores cuando se sale de pantalla? un saludo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Elenasys! eso me ha ayudado mucho...pero ahora tengo otro problema...cuando relleno el primer edittext, hago scroll hacia abajo hasta el ultimo elemento, y vuelvo al primer elemento, se ha reiniciado y puesto el edittext vacio....

como puedo hacer para que se quede quieto y no reinicie los valores cuando se sale de pantalla? un saludo! :)